# Tree Menu Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a menu with the following structure in the database:

```
MenuItems
  id
  menu_text
  id_parent
```

Where `id_parent` is null, this is a menu root, and if `id_parent` is not null, this is a part of submenu.  I need to create a method to return an tree of this contenxt, and then return a string with `<UL> <LI>` sctructure to render in my webpage.

I cannot figure out the query to select all of the menus and their direct sub menus at once.

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to create something to return the recursive data!

Comment: So you asking to code for you...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use T-SQL to generate a XML file.. You Can use cursor inside your query to append the child elements and wrap it under the parent UL.

I have tried a sample. You can a have a look at this..

http://doitdotnet.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/generate-a-xml-from-sql/